# Endless or infinite scrolling for panorama image

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement infinite scrolling for a UIImageView (which is subview of a scrollview) having a panorama image. When the user would reach at the end by scrolling manually, the same image should start again.

An example panorama image : [image: Sample Panorama Image]

Comment: You mean 360 degree view

Comment: Not 360 degree but linear infinite in horizontal direction (left and right scrolling).

Comment: See this repositary might be helpful for you https://github.com/iSame7/Panoramic

Comment: I have tried this already. This repository doesn't provide endless scrolling, rather it scrolls the image based on motion sensor.

Comment: if you want to infinite scrolling then go with https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: iCarousel is for multiple images, I only have one static image.

Comment: There are plenty of examples around of "infinite scrolling" or, better, "circular scrolling" --- find a good one. Instead of creating "new" views / images for each scroll page/panel, just use the same image every time.

Comment: Simply add two copies of the image. Adjust the scroll position back to middle each time the user scrolls to either end.

Comment: Adjusting back the scroll position wont give a jerk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up creating a scrollview with having a horizontal stackview inside it. The stackview would be dynamically adding and deleting the views as the user would scroll to the end. 
The trick is to reset the `contentOffset` after adding or removing the view, so the user will experience a seamless infinite scrolling.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 0 {
        addPanoramaViewFromStackView(atPosition: 0)
        removePanoramaViewFromStackView(atPosition: 1)
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * ratio
    }

    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width)) {
        addPanoramaViewFromStackView(atPosition: 2)
        removePanoramaViewFromStackView(atPosition: 0)
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x - UIScreen.main.bounds.height * ratio
    }
}
```

`ratio` is the ratio between width and height of panorama image. Since the image will be taking up entire height of the device, it's width will be calculated by ratio.

Comment: I have image and want to move from down to up and when image finished repeat that image and this loop repeats and repeats how can I do that ?